# conditional statement in razor view

Tags: razor, c#-4.0

I have a property in razor view. And I want to have to get a conditional statement.
So if the checkbox is checked do that. else do other thing.

This is the property:

```
 var inclusiefInactieveMedwerker = (bool)ViewData["InclusiefInactieveMedwerker"];
```

And I try the conditional statement like this:

```
 <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-4 selectie-title">
                <input class="k-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="medewerkUitDienst"  "@if(inclusiefInactieveMedwerker == true ?  checked==true : "")"  />  <label class="k-checkbox-label" for="medewerkUitDienst">inclusief uit dienst</label>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `checked` attribute if condition is *true* using conditional operator.

```
<input class="k-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="medewerkUitDienst"  @(inclusiefInactieveMedwerker ?  "checked" : "")  />
```

Comment: Thank you very nice